# PHP + Apache + 1C

Tags: php, apache, 1с

Имеется опубликованная база 1С на веб сервере Apache.
К Apache привязан PHP.
Когда ввожу адрес `localhost:8045/base1`, почему-то пролетает мимо php. Однако если я введу `localhost:8045`, он войдет в систему.

Искал в интернете описания не нашел. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это исправить?

`httpd.conf`:

```
Listen 8045
PHPIniDir "C:/SERVER/BIN/PHP"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
LoadModule php_module "C:/SERVER/BIN/PHP/php8apache2_4.dll"
DocumentRoot "c:/SERVER/DATA"
<Directory "c:/SERVER/DATA">

# 1c publication
Alias "/base1" "C:/Server/DATA/1C/"
<Directory "C:/Server/DATA/1C/">
    AllowOverride All
    Options None
    Require all granted
    SetHandler 1c-application
    ManagedApplicationDescriptor "C:/Server/DATA/1C/default.vrd"
</Directory>
```

Comment: Более подробно объясните чего Вы ожидаете ? Как php должен взаимодействовать с 1С ?

Comment: @santavital
Суть задачи следующая.
Есть один сервис, который отправляет по http сервису данные в базу 1С. Аутентификация происходит по Basic.
Проблема в следующем. Этот сервис обязывает при некорректно отправленной аутентификации от сервиса,  должны вернуть код ответа не 401, а 200 с обязательным содержанием json ответа.

Планировал это реализовать через php реализовать. 
Все в целом работает, php обрабатывает как положено, но работает только если обращаться непосредственно к самому ServerName (localhost:8045), вместо "localhost:8045/base1". Если ввести последний адрес, то код будет 401.

Comment: Вы хотите перехватить этот http запрос своим php сервисом не отдавая 1С, выполнить необходимые действия и вернуть ответ ? Думаю такой вариант невозможен.

Comment: @santavital предполагал что можно перехватить код 401 который вернулся из 1С и его перенапривать на JSON с кодом 200. А как иначе можно?

Comment: в 1С создайте расширение, проанализируйте какой код возвращает 401, добавьте в расширение соответствующий модуль (содержащий код) исправьте код ответа на 200